# Android Material ButtonToggleGroup get checkedButtonId

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

In last versions meterial ButtonToggleGroup support singleSelection and selectionRequired

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'

 app:selectionRequired="true"
 app:singleSelection="true
```

it works well, but when I try to get the id of the already selected button, returns -1

```
var x = toggleGroup.checkedButtonId
```

How can I get checked button id always?
I understand that -1 indicates that the current button is already selected. But I have several toggleGroup and I need to know on the fly which buttons id are selected.

Comment: The method [getCheckedButtonId()](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup.java#L394) return -1 when the group is not in single selection mode.

Comment: i checked i have app:singleSelection="true" in xml alsо with debuger and isSingleSelection() which return "true" in code run. Perhaps this problem is because I use "View Binding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolve this problem use isChecked parametr in method addOnButtonCheckedListener

```
    binding.toggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->

        if (isChecked){

           //You code here
       }
    }
```